# Infinite recursion error - how to solve?

Tags: r, function, recursion, replication, infinite-recursion

Still new to R so trying to practice working with functions, I have created some (probably quite inefficient) code which I will look at modifying later, currently it returns the result I need but I want to repeat the simulation 100 times within the function itself.  This would effectively be turn[i] which returns outcomes -1 or 1 with a specified function probability:

```
game = function(n,pr) {
turn = cumsum(2*rbinom(n,1,prob=pr)-1)
bankrupcy.test = which(turn == -25)
winner.test = which(turn == 50)
if(length(bankrupcy.test)==0){bankrupcy.test=c(0)}
if(length(winner.test)==0){winner.test=c(0)}
if(bankrupcy.test==0 && winner.test==0){turn[n]}else
if(bankrupcy.test[1]>winner.test[1]){-25}else{
50}
return(replicate(100,game(n)))
}
```

I have tried creating a for loop but I can't seem to structure that correctly, hence I am looking to use the replicate command within the function I created, however I recieve the following error:

"evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /options(expressions=)"

Where am I going wrong?  I want to return a vector with 100 outcomes of the above simulation, in which the game is played until 50 profit is made or a 25 loss is made, whichever occurs first.  If neither of the previous outcomes occur then the final value of the vector is taken.

Comment: You are calling `game` from inside the function, and so `game` ends up calling itself. This is causing the recursion.

Comment: I figured that might be the case but how else can I replicate the simulation within the function?  Is the only way a for loop?  I can never seem to get those to work if the function gets even slightly complicated...

Comment: is there a reason you want the replication within the function? if you remove the `return(replicate(100,game(n)))` and then outside the function run `replicate(100, game(n = n, pr = pr))` it should work (but maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do)

Comment: I want to add to the function further, so there will be additional factors which are reliant on the final vector being of 100 simulations (or more), so I have a sample of data to return information about.  I will expand the function to several more variables (function(x,y,z....) and with only one result in the vector it isn't possible to do this as of yet.

Comment: Can you give an example input? I.e. some values for `n` and `pr` when you call the function for the first time?

Comment: Think of it as coin flips for this example, where n is the number of times the coin is flipped and pr is the probability of winning which is 0.5.  Currently you start at 25 cash, later I will add in income as a variable, but each turn you bet 1 coin and either win +1 or lose -1.  The cumsum function shows your progress over n coin flips.  If you end up with a "net loss" of 25 then the game ends, I didn't cut the vector short but simply ensured that if this value was found in the vector then the value -25 is returned.  A similar concept it used for "backing out" if a profit of 50 is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n <- 1000
pr <- 0.50

game <- function(n, pr) {
  result = 
    replicate(100, {{turn = cumsum(2*rbinom(n, 1,prob=pr)-1)
      bankrupcy.test = which(turn == -25)
      winner.test = which(turn == 50)
      if(length(bankrupcy.test)==0){bankrupcy.test = 0}
      if(length(winner.test)==0){winner.test = 0}
      if(bankrupcy.test==0 && winner.test==0){turn[n]} else
        if(bankrupcy.test[1]>winner.test[1]) {-25} else {50}
      }})
  return(result)
}

game(n, pr)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the result I am looking for, the only issue is getting the "function within a function" to return the 100 value vector if I write game(1000, 0.5).  As soon as I start trying to do that within the curly brackets errors keep coming into play.

Comment: See my edit. I've moved the `replicate` function inside the `game` function. No need to call the same function recursively, and now whatever that function needs to do later has access to the result. :)

Comment: For good practice, it is probably better to move the code inside the curly braces into its own function with a different name, and then have the `game` procedure call that function. And also to make the number of simulations dynamic, but it works.